# Weak References in Perl

Tags: perl, garbage-collection

How to create weak references to the objects in perl, so when object goes out of scope, the reference count is released?
I have tried using the DESTROY sub to break the circular references.

```
sub DESTROY{  
my $p = shift;  
delete $p->{__tree__};  
delete $p->{tokenizers};  
delete $p->{toke};  
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You can't "call" destroy - the problem here is that perl works on reference counting - each reference to a thing is counted, and it is *only* when the ref count drops to zero, that it may be released/destroyed/garbage collected.

`DESTROY` is a special method that is called within an object to do cleanup tasks *when this happens*. It doesn't delete the object, it just lets it do some final tidying when it dies.

Have a look at the [`Scalar::Util`](http://search.cpan.org/%7Epevans/Scalar-List-Utils-1.42/lib/Scalar/Util.pm#weaken) module. It includes the `weaken` method which does exactly what you asked.

> The lvalue $ref will be turned into a weak reference. This means that it will not hold a reference count on the object it references. Also when the reference count on that object reaches zero, the reference will be set to undef. This function mutates the lvalue passed as its argument and returns no value.
>
> This is useful for keeping copies of references, but you don't want to prevent the object being DESTROY-ed at its usual time.

Comment: Only certain lvalues can be used, and the limitations aren't documented. Calling 'weaken' on an lvalue function that returns a scalar does NOT work.

Answer (score 4):

From [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html):

> You can break circular references by creating a "weak reference". A weak reference does not increment the reference count for a variable, which means that the object can go out of scope and be destroyed. You can weaken a reference with the weaken function exported by the [Scalar::Util](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html) module.

Here's how we can make the first example safer:

```
use Scalar::Util 'weaken';
my $foo = {};
my $bar = { foo => $foo };
$foo->{bar} = $bar;
weaken $foo->{bar};
```

> The reference from `$foo` to `$bar` has been weakened. When the `$bar` variable goes out of scope, it will be garbage-collected. The next time you look at the value of the `$foo->{bar} key`, it will be `undef`.
>
> This action at a distance can be confusing, so you should be careful with your use of weaken. You should weaken the reference in the variable that will go out of scope *first*. That way, the longer-lived variable will contain the expected reference until it goes out of scope.

Comment: Though, it works fine, could there be any other solution beside using Scalar::Util 'weaken' ?

Comment: You can reinvent wheel.